# Flexbox wrap to next line with available space

Tags: css, flexbox

Using Flexbox I can not seem to make a div wrap to a new line without having it break with previous block content.

I made a codepen to explain:

```css
.container {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.lightpink {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
  margin 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="lightblue"></div>
  <div class="lightpink"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

What I want is for the red block to display inline, to the right of my lightblue block.

Can you tell me how to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: That is not possible with Flexbox and the existing markup. With `flex-direction: column` one can, though that will take fixed heights and inner scrolling. `float` can do this, or with a markup change if to keep Flexbox

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.lightpink {
  background-color: lightpink;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

body {
   margin 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="lightblue" ></div>
  <div>
      <div class="lightpink" ></div>
      <div class="red" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You just wrap `.lightpink`, `.red` in `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding these 3 lines to your container.

```
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100px;
  align-content: flex-start;
```

See the fiddle for working example. https://jsfiddle.net/meercha/yn9gtnpc/1/